# Cannot save document to folder when logged on as adminstrator

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-permissions

I am logged onto a Windows 2012 server as administrator.  I open a document in C:\inetpub\wwwroot with notepad to edit it.  When I save, it tells me I cannot save it, would I like to save to desktop instead.

What exactly is occurring here?  Why would it not let me save it despite being logged on as Admin?

I can of course Edit on the desktop, and copy and paste to the location where it then says I need Administrative permissions, and then allows it.  But I want to understand what is going on with the permissions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notepad doesn't launch with elevated permissions by default, so you have to run notepad as administrator and then open the file using the file open dialog before you can save changes back to the original file.

Answer (score -1):

Rightclick on Notepad and Start as administrator. That should help.